# Exec --no-startup-id <command> says "--" invalid option

Tags: linux, bash, exec

I'm trying to launch applications without "wait cursor", according to [i3 userguide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_automatically_starting_applications_on_i3_startup) I should use `--no-statrup-id` option of exec but it gives me "impossible" error.

```
$ exec --no-startup-id firefox
bash: exec: --: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
```

Can anybody explain to me what's wrong? In every manual, I find that people use this flag, but `man exec` have no information about this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax written in *i3 userguide* is for your *i3 config file*, if you want to run it in your shell use the `i3-msg` command

```
i3-msg exec --no-startup-id firefox
```

Find in [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) about builtin like `exec`:

> Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented as accepting options preceded by ‘-’ accepts ‘--’ to signify the end of the options.

EDIT:
I can launch firefox, my output return 0 and a *true*

```
i3-msg: unrecognized option '--no-startup-id'
[{"success":true}]
```

I take a look on [i3 source](https://github.com/i3/i3) and I find something interesting
*parser-specs/config.spec* :

```
# <exec|exec_always> [--no-startup-id] command
state EXEC:
  no_startup_id = '--no-startup-id'
    ->
  command = string
    -> call cfg_exec($exectype, $no_startup_id, $command)
```

*parser-specs/commands.spec* :

```
# exec [--no-startup-id] <command>
state EXEC:
  nosn = '--no-startup-id'
    ->
  command = string
    -> call cmd_exec($nosn, $command)
```

But I'ven't enough skills in grammar to go further.

Comment: `i3-msg: unrecognized option '--no-startup-id'`

Comment: This option not working for me in I3 config too, but it's another question. Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use quotation marks to keep i3-msg from parsing the argument.

```
 user  ~ | MyDE  i3-msg exec --no-startup-id /home/mbp/MyDE/xrandr/dock.sh
i3-msg: unrecognized option '--no-startup-id'
 user  ~ | MyDE  i3-msg "exec --no-startup-id /home/mbp/MyDE/xrandr/dock.sh"
[{"success":true}]
```

Comment: I love you!! man...!